# Can I avoid serving all js to clients not logged in?

Tags: javascript, security, web-applications, meteor

When building a Meteor app, is it possible to NOT serve/load all generated javascript to the client, until the user is authenticated?

I would be happier if not anybody could see my templates, models, helpers etc...

**Clarification:**
This is not about putting stuff under /server, or doing the right thing with pub/sub.
It is about not sending more than necessary to unauthenticated users, not because it is a security risk, but simply to hide as much as possible from the world.

Comment: @rebeliagamer - I'm new here and wish to learn, so please bear with me. 
I'm curious as to why you changed the tags: I figure web-applications and JavaScript are given with the meteor tag, and therefore redundant or even misleading as this question has no relevance to anything not meteor? 
The security tag does add a bit though...

Comment: All about tags is to help navigate through threads. If I have problem with `Swing` I would expect `Java` tag also, it isn't that weird I think. Last but not least, your question is about `authentication` so it is the security topic. :)

Comment: Unsure on meteor, but for this I'd load the scripts in with the server side language.  E.g. with PHP, `if (session value = correct) { //load script }` can't see it being much different on others for what ever server side you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the [router](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/router) package to accomplish this.

In your main html file, you add `{{renderPage}}` where you would like the router to render templates. Then when you define your routes, you can specify which template/templates get rendered based on the path, and any other variables.

If you wanted to, for instance, show a login screen without rendering any of the protected templates, you could do the following:

```
Meteor.Router.page();
Meteor.Router.add({
  '/': function() {                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
      return 'protectedContentTemplate';
    }   
    else {
      return 'userUnauthorizedTemplate';
    }   
  },  
});
```

Of course, you should always have your collections locked down with `Meteor.publish()` and `Collection.allow()` functions so that unauthorized users cannot get access to information they shouldn't have access too.

Comment: Both 'protectedContentTemplate' and 'userUnauthorizedTemplate' will be available on the client before authentication, if looking through the served js. I wish to avoid having 'protectedContentTemplate' et.al. served to the unauthenticated client.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure how to do that, it seems like there should be some form of template restrictions though. Theoretically there shouldn't be any sensitive information in the template system, but I could see where filtering published templates by the current user's state and role could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to selectively load scripts within a Meteor app at this time. The one exception is that you can protect any sensitive code by putting it in the `/server` directory (which does not get sent to the client) and lock down data as @Patrick Coffey suggested (also making use of Meteor `method`s). If you do this, you don't have to reveal your full model schema, authentication rules, or sensitive algorithms to the client, and you can tightly control which records and even fields of records are visible to the client. It works well, and you can choose the level of convenience/performance vs. security you want by how open-ended you make your API.

If your templates and helpers are sensitive, you'll have to wait until server-side rendering is introduced ([it's on the roadmap](https://trello.com/c/Lz07fBAm/7-server-side-rendering)) or cook up your own solution without Meteor's help, but I think there may be a reason to look a little deeper at the question. The premise of your concern appears to be that authenticated users will somehow be more trustworthy than non-authenticated users, but in most situations (even inside a company), there is a likelihood of there being users that are also untrustworthy – or users whose accounts get hacked - and these people will always have access to anything you send to the browser. So from that perspective, it makes sense to be sure you don't put important secrets in templates or client-side code regardless. For most apps, though, templates and helpers will not be sensitive, and if you set up your server well, hacked templates won't be able to access anything that normal templates can't.

Comment: I don't have any special need to hide stuff from authenticated users - other than by use of the usual best practices you mention. I simply want to avoid sending the entire client-part of the app to unauthenticated clients, they need not get even a glimpse of my ingenious code :-)

Comment: :D Fair enough!  Barring some serious hacking, I'd say "watch this space" is probably the best answer for now. Things should change somewhat as the framework edges toward 1.0, slated for "early 2014." Even then, I'm not 100% sure your concerns will be fully addressed, so if this is a deal-breaker, I'd recommend caution. This is my personal  speculation, though; I'm not associated with MDG in any way.

Comment: It's no deal-breaker - the benefits of Meteor justifies this "inconvenience" by far. But it would be nice to have a feature of white-listing a few routes/templates to be the only public ones...